# Change the physical location of the device (React Native)

Tags: react-native, gps

I am planning to make an application where the user can input a address and the location of the device would change. I saw a lots of people changing the location of the simulator but I would like to change the location of the actual device. An example: If I am living in California, I would like to show my device is in New York even the device is still in California but in the GPS it would show as new york.

How could I achieve this functionality using React Native or NodeJS.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want this  user custom location to be  specific for your app only  ?

Comment: Yes, just a simple input field and when I type a location it would change the gps to that address or location entered. If the device is in California and when I type NY the device is still physically in California but gps and maps is showing as is it in New York

Comment: This is possible only for your app only, other apps installed on the device can get real location. But you can do this for your app only so other app users can see mocked location

Comment: I see , that’s still fine for me too however, do you know a way I could do this any npm library

Comment: The easy way is to use `react-native-maps` and user tap the map for where s/he want to be located and you save that location (latitude and longitude) as user preferred location. other users will find user located on that place

Comment: Feel free to reach at me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com for further information